# Redraw Issues in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, redraw, html-rendering, webpage-rendering

I am experiencing redraw issues in Chrome that I can't explain. They don't appear in any other browser. The website is http://leonardo.re

They appear after hovering over a styled `DIV` containing a styled link (contact page):

[image: Example Redraw Issue in Chrome]

And sometimes on an overlaying `DIV` when scrolling (any page). Not always though:

[image: Example Redraw Issue in Chrome (2)]

Does anyone know what exactly is going on or how this can be solved / avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has now been resolved in newer versions of Chrome - no more issues!

Comment: Nope, I still have it right now, especially in pages which use custom styled tooltips - when the tooltip disappears, it leaves traces. Chrome version 26.0.1410.64.